# QGIS Intersection is returning with an error

Tags: intersection, shapefile, qgis

I am trying to run "Intersection" on two different shapefiles (Shape1, Shape2). The first one is with the purple colour and the second with the blue.

- Previously I've run "Check validity", "Multiparts to singleparts" and "Simplify geometries" just to make things more easy.

When I run Intersection between the two shapefiles I get the message "GEOS geoprocessing error: One or more input features have invalid geometry".

Update: After doing "Validity Check" I didn't had any "Invalid Output" results, only "Valid outuput" even after changing the "Method" from GEOS to QGIS and "the one selected in digitizing settings", so I do not really figured out what is the problem.

I am new at this. Any ideas please?

[The two different shapefiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7UPN.png)

[SHP1 adn SHP2 through Intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjFWB.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkK6a.png)

Comment: did you check this thread and the solution there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259256/qgis-invalid-geometry-even-after-using-validity-checker-and-v-clean

Comment: Yes! I checked it before posting this thread, so I' m gonna add that I didn't had any "Invalid output" from validity check so that people will know that the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Try using Saga GIS intersect tool in processing tools. If you have characters problems in output shape, change coding in layer properties